# Editing lines from multiple files as if from one

Tags: software-rec, editors

I'm looking for a program that can read lines from many files at once and allows editing them and saving them back after changes. It may seem a weird idea at first glance, but it's quite simple and the software can be very useful for working with configurations. Especially those spread like this:

```
tomas@tomas:/etc/sysctl.d$ ls
10-console-messages.conf  10-link-restrictions.conf  10-ptrace.conf    README
10-ipv6-privacy.conf      10-magic-sysrq.conf        10-zeropage.conf
10-kernel-hardening.conf  10-network-security.conf   99-sysctl.conf
```

So it would be no surprise if it already exists.

To rephrase, I'd like to get from all of the files from the listing above (but `README`) those lines that are either:

- uncommented
- commented with a character following right after `#`

Then I want to be able to comment, uncomment, or change the value - **interactively**, as in a text editor. And finally I want to save the changes.

Is there a special mode to `vim` or other popular terminal editors that facilitates this? Or is there possibly an edition tool designed for this kind of tasks in particular?

Comment: You can open multiple files with vim, and [ask it to hide lines that do not match a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862966/hide-all-notmatching-lines-in-vim). This solves most your problems but doesn't display the multilples files in a single window : you will have to edit each file separately, then save and quit/next to get to the next one. I wouldn't be surprised if there was a way to display multiple files in a single window, but I didn't find it. Tabs could be a good alternative too

Comment: @Aaron That's close, but missing the point.

Comment: how is it? I haven't tested the solution but I expected you to be able to edit these lines and save the result without removing the hidden lines from the file

Comment: @Aaron Well, I demand luxury.

Comment: Alright, so my previous suggestion didn't miss the point, but you'd like it to go further and display all the files on a single page, right? I just want to make sure before searching for a solution, I expect it to be possible :)

Comment: Well actually nevermind, I've researched it for 10 minutes and couldn't find anything. I still think it's possible (I'm always surprised by the complexity of tasks vim can handle), but will need to wait for the input of an expert. Maybe you would have more luck on the [vi SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) btw. In the meantime, you should try the `:global` + tabs solution if you haven't already, I'm sure you'd find it nearly as efficient

Comment: Forget tabs, splitscreen would be closer to what you want (although a little more messy imo) : you would be able to see the content of all the files on the same screen. `vim -o file1 file2 ...`, then apply the `:global` (there certainly is a way to apply it from command line, but I don't know it)

Comment: @Aaron This about it this way. A few years ago there was a huge central Apache config file. Then it was broken down into many small ones, similar to  the listing in my question. The benefit is clarity and logic. But there is this downside that this question is about.

Comment: Hmmm you could still use a single-file configuration with apache I think, just put everything in the httpd.conf rather than making it reference the other conf files. I would find that awful, but to each his own I guess.

Comment: @Aaron But I want to have it both ways. :-)

Comment: Alright, well hope for an answer from someone more knowledgeable in vim than I am ;)